# How can I create simple Django chat based on WebSockets with PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-channels

I try to create Django backed using WebSockets in accordance with [Django documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#). I would like to receive message, save it to my PostgreSQL database and send response to the same user. At this moment message may be the same as received. I try to do it in the way shown below, but I get:

```
django_1  | 2017-08-31 08:30:52,050 - ERROR - worker - Error processing message with consumer backend.consumers.msg_consumer:
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/worker.py", line 119, in run
django_1  |     consumer(message, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/code/backend/consumers.py", line 11, in msg_consumer
django_1  |     message=message.content['message'],
django_1  | KeyError: 'message'
```

routing.py:

```
from channels.routing import route
from backend.consumers import ws_connect, ws_receive, ws_disconnect, msg_consumer

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
    route("chat", msg_consumer),
]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Message(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

consumers.py:

```
from channels import Group
from .models import  Message
from channels import Channel
import json


# Connected to chat-messages
def msg_consumer(message):
    # Save to model
    Message.objects.create(
        data=json.loads(message['text']),
        message = data['message']
    )
    # Broadcast to listening sockets
    Group("chat").send({
        "text": message.content['message'],
    })

# Connected to websocket.connect
def ws_connect(message):
    # Accept the connection
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    # Add to the chat group
    Group("chat").add(message.reply_channel)

# Connected to websocket.receive
def ws_receive(message):
    Channel("chat").send({
        "text": message.content['text'],
    })
    print(message.content['text'])

# Connected to websocket.disconnect
def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group("chat").discard(message.reply_channel)
```

I have changed:

```
Message.objects.create(
    message=message.content['message'],
)
```

to

```
Message.objects.create(
    data=json.loads(message['text']),
    message = data['message']
)
```

Comment: you see what message['text'] is

Comment: I send just simple String.

Comment: print message， type(message)  many try   message.content['text']

Comment: Sorry I don't uderstand. You want to see what contains `message['text']` in `msg_consumer` I have to print it?

Comment: sorry， you see what message.content['text'] is

Comment: Yes, it's string that I send using Simple WebSocket Client in Chrome extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from channels import Group
from .models import Message
from channels import Channel


def msg_consumer(message):
    text = message.content.get('text')
    Message.objects.create(
        message=text,
    )
    Group("chat").send({'text': text})


def ws_connect(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    Group("chat").add(message.reply_channel)


def ws_receive(message):
    Channel("chat").send({
        "text": message.content['text'],
    })


def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group("chat").discard(message.reply_channel)
```

**Updated solution**

Comment: With your `msg_consumer` I get the same error as it is in updated question: `django_1  |     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
django_1  | json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
`

Comment: @Wahtdbogh, Please provide what contains in your "message" variable.

Comment: You mean `print("message "+message)` in `msg_consumer`?

Comment: @Wahtdbogh, Actually i mean something like print(message, message.content['text']) :)

Comment: When I add `print(message, message.content['text'])` after `Message.objects.create` in `msg_consumer` it doesn't print anything. Error seems to be in `Message.objects.create`.

Comment: I added traceback associated with your solution in updated question.

Comment: @Wahtbogh, move out data=json.loads(message['text']) from Message.objects.create . You can't define a variable inside method call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153339/discussion-between-valeriy-gaydar-and-wahtdbogh).

Answer (score 1):

```
def msg_consumer(message):
    # Save to model
    Message.objects.create(
        message = message.content['text']
    )
    # Broadcast to listening sockets
    Group("chat").send({
        "text": message.content['text'],
    })
```

you try, If this does not work, I do not know, sorry